# CENTOS apache ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /path/to/shell.sh is not working

Tags: apache-2.4, bash, shell, sudo, centos8

Trying to do a web interface IPtables management.

Created a file **test.php**

```
$output = shell_exec('sudo bash /usr/bin/iptables.sh 2>&1');
echo $output;
```

Gave /usr/bin/iptables.sh NOPASSWD so I can execute the file with sudo through apache without using a password

```
sudo iptables -L
```

sudoers file :

```
apache ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/iptables.sh
```

But I am still getting error

> We trust you have received the usual lecture from the local System
> Administrator. It usually boils down to these three things: #1)
> Respect the privacy of others. #2) Think before you type. #3) With
> great power comes great responsibility. sudo: a terminal is required
> to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard
> input or configure an askpass helper{"mode":"full","isActive":false}

However, if I use

```
apache ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Everything works fine.

I double-checked my directory and I used the exact path

```
[root@CentOS bin]# readlink -f iptables.sh
/usr/bin/iptables.sh
```

Super clueless here, can anyone help me with a direction? :'(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you call with `sudo` must match what is in the `sudoers` file, but in your case they do not match.

You tried to run `bash /usr/bin/iptables.sh`, but `sudoers` only allows you to run `/usr/bin/iptables.sh`.

Comment: I am confused, how am I supposed to execute the script in this case? Do I have to add bash to sudoers?

Comment: @alvan Why do you have `bash` in there at all? It is redundant. You can do what you want but the important bit is that **they must match exactly**.

Comment: Oh, Oh my god. 
$output = shell_exec("sudo /usr/bin/iptables.sh 2>&1'");
This actually worked

Comment: Thank you so much Michael!!

Answer (score 0):

Try with sudo, since `/usr/bin/iptables.sh` references to root of root.

```
$output = shell_exec("sudo -u root sh -c 'bash /usr/bin/iptables.sh 2>&1'");
echo $output;
```

Comment: No luck, the php doesn't output anything in this case.

But when I change the sudoers file to ALL, this works

Comment: @alvan have you tried above code without nopassword in sudoers like  -> apache ALL=(root) /usr/bin/iptables.sh ; What is the output of <?php echo exec('whoami'); ?>

Comment: it is apache    15 characters